# F# Async workflow

Tags: f#

Is there a way to look at the definition of the Async workflow? What goes under the hood that would make a line of code behave differently in there, than outside of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "the Async workflow", you mean the `AsyncBuilder` type which defines the behavior of `async` blocks, then you can find the definition in the control.fs file in the source distribution, in the source\fsharp\FSharp.Core folder.

The translation of a computation expression into method calls on the builder instance can be found in the [F# spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc264041892).

Comment: +1 for the spec.  Especially, if you understand how LINQ works in C# (syntax rewriting into method calls), you can grok how F# workflows work by translating into method calls on the builder object.  If you're curious about the specific details of async, then look at control.fs in the source code.

Comment: where does one get the fs source from?

Comment: @akaphenom - The source comes with the F# 2.0 release for VS 2008 (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=444005fb-e627-4feb-b51d-13d6a3b4b8ed).  I'm not sure if it's also included in the VS 2010 installation out of the box...

Answer (score 5):

Adding to kvb's advice, relevant Don's "Expert F#" chapter is available online:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/b/b/6/bb666ebe-e643-496f-b290-03527d157b47/Expert.F.Sharp_Ch13_8504Syme.pdf

It includes a short but informative "Under the Hood" section.